# php jquery like selector engine

Tags: php, dom, css-selectors, traversal

Does anyone know a library that allows DOM traversing in strings using a jquery like selector engine?

Comment: Most of the 3rd party libs given in [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662) can do that. On a sidenote, they are not *jQuery selectors* but [W3C selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html)

Comment: yeah, thanks. I just wanted to be the clearer is possible :o)

Comment: hwr, if you post your comment as an answer i would mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Many out there, pick one that suits you:

- http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/
- http://querypath.org/
- http://jquery.hohli.com/
- http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

few more can be found in similar question (link thanks to @Gordon) [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Comment: I would also suggest QueryPath http://querypath.org/. it's very similar to phpQuery but the references are a lot better. which one dp you think could be better?

Comment: Note: QueryPath requires Ctype PHP extension to be available.