# Using PHP to split text into 2 halves at punctuation or closed html tag

Tags: php, html

We have scoured the web for a simple solution to this, but no luck so far.

We are splitting our $text into two halves, ensuring that the split ONLY occurs at the end a sentence (.?!):

```
$middle=strrpos(substr($text, 0, floor(strlen($text) / 2)), ' ') + 1;
$adjust = strcspn($text, '.!?', $middle);
echo substr($text, 0, $middle+$adjust+1);
```

This works fine. However, we need to expand the functionality to also split when a sentence ends with quote marks or a closed HTML tag. For example:

`."` OR `?"` OR `!"` OR `</em>` OR `</h1>` etc.

For example, this text:

This is a sentence without quotes and html tags. `<em>`"This is some text with quotes and a html tag."`</em>` Is this text without "quotes" and html tags at the end of sentence? "Yes, that text is without quotes and html tags!"

should be split into:

This is a sentence without quotes and html tags. `<em>`"This is some text with a quote and a html tag."`</em>`

and

Is this text without "quotes" and html tags at the end of sentence? "Yes, that text is without quotes and html tags!"

Any ideas how we could achieve this?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: [php jquery like selector engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417446/php-jquery-like-selector-engine)

You can probably find an easy way to use that.