# SimpleXML extract text between two tags

Tags: simplexml

I am sorry if this is a stupid question but i am new to programming. I just want to know how to extract text between two tags. For example, if i have the html below:

```
<div class="s1">
    <a href="blablabla">Hi</a>
</div>
<div class="s2">
    <a href="blablabla">Hello</a>
</div>
```

The expected output is to extract the @href in class s1 and the text Hi.

Comment: programing language? Javascript?

Comment: is it possible to do it in php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that this is easy in JavaScript with the JQuery Library. In PHP it is also possible ([php jquery like selector engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417446/php-jquery-like-selector-engine))